# How to reduce multiple nested foreach blocks

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

I have the following scenario:

```
var Ids = object1.GetIds(); // returns IEnumerable<int>
foreach (var id in Ids)
{
    foreach (var relatedObject in object1.GetRelatedObjects(id))
    {
    // Do Something with related object
    }
}
```

In this case, i want to get rid of from the first foreach and reduce this logic into single foreach. How could i achieve this?

Should it be possible with LINQ expression some similar methodology?

Comment: if you're using EF, there should be some property like `object1.RelatedObjects`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When there is nothing between the two loops, before or after the nested one, you can use `SelectMany` to "flatten" two loops into one:

```
foreach (var relatedObject in Ids.SelectMany(object1.GetRelatedObjects)) {
    ...
}
```

One major difference between this loop and the loop that you have is that `id` is no longer in scope. Assuming that `relatedObject` exposes a public `Id` property, this should not be a problem in your situation, because you could extract the `id` back with

```
var id = relatedObject.Id;
```

Comment: Exactly, just what i wanted. Thanks

Comment: I feel like this wouldn't actually offer any performance bonuses at all (I even suspect the contrary), so at best all it would do is hurt readability IMO. So yes, it's what OP asked for, but I'm not sure I'd recommend actually using it.

Comment: This statement also can be reduced into following i think: 

foreach(var relatedObject in Ids.SelectMany(object.GetRelatedObjects){
  ...
}

Comment: @stackerflow You are right, it's better to rewrite with method group syntax.

Comment: @Abion47 When you want two loops to behave like one loop on flattened hierarchy, writing the code with one loop improves readability by staying closer to what you actually wanted to express. Compare "process objects related to IDs from the list" vs. "take IDs from the list, find their related objects, and process them." Eliminating the intermediate step makes the logic easier to follow; the same thing happens in code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I disagree. Flattening the two loops into one hides what is really going on, and can make the logic _harder_ to follow. You haven't eliminated an intermediary loop, you've only abstracted it away from the immediate view. The logic still plays out as "take IDs from the list, find their related objects, and process them", except now you have to be familiar with LINQ to know that's what is happening. And even if you do know LINQ, a `foreach` is easier to understand at a glance than a `SelectMany`.

Comment: A thought, though. Your logical approach would make more sense if you instead moved the `SelectMany` to after `object1.GetIds()` and renamed `Ids` to `RelatedObjects`. That would separate the LINQ from within the `foreach` and make the entire thing more readable as well as easier to follow.

Comment: i.e. `var RelatedObjects = object1.GetIds().SelectMany(object1.GetRelatedObjects); foreach (var relatedObject in RelatedObjects) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like to take full advantage of the optional braces/block for `foreach` loops.

You can't reduce the complexity. But you can make it look nicer

```
IEnumerable<int> Ids = object1.GetIds()

foreach (var id in Ids)
foreach (var relatedObject in object1.GetRelatedObjects(id))
{
     DoSomething(relatedObject);
}
```

Comment: In my experience, Visual Studio doesn't like to have this same-line nested blocks sometimes, but when it decides to go along with it, damn does it look smooth.